# How to make an <option> a default value in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I want to have an `<option>` from a `<select>` menu to be selected as default, not just "seen" as the default like when using `<option selected="selected">`.
I tried using `onload` event but the page keeps reloading indefinitely and won't allow to select other options.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body onload="document.stringForm.submit();">

<form method="post" name="stringForm" id="stringForm">
<select name="stringSelect">
   <option>one string</option>
   <option>two string</option>
   <option>three string</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="foo">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["foo"]))
{
    $vString = $_POST["string"];    
    echo $vString;
}
?>
```

Sorry if this is bad question. First time post.

Edit:
The purpose for this is to make a value appear on screen by default when the page loads.

Comment: `<option selected="selected" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: why are you immediatly submitting the form the instant the page loads? The user won't get a chance to select anything!

Comment: *not just "seen" as the default like when using `<option selected="selected">.`* — This doesn't make sense. The selected attribute is how you make it the default. It isn't any kind of visual illusion.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. There is not ‘default’ in HTML. Using `selected="selected"` is the way to select which one shows up. Are you asking how to make one show up using PHP?

Comment: "I tried using onload event but the page keeps reloading indefinitely"  — You're using it to submit the form. What did you expect that to do?!

Comment: Like already said above. When an option is marked as `selected` it would be displayed AND sent when you submit your form. You cannot dissociate these two behaviours.

Comment: The purpose is that when the page loads the value will be submitted as default, but when another is selected the content in `$vString` would be replaced with the selected string when the user hits the submit button

Comment: If you're just doing this for a test to see what *exactly* is submitted when you auto-submit a form; try changing `echo $vString;` to `die($vString);` - that'll stop the script executing and you'll not end up looping ad infinitum.

Comment: @Jerry your comment above is *exactly* how `<option selected>` behaves. The default value will be submitted if the user just loads the page and submits the form. Otherwise their chosen value will be submitted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't be submitting a form on page load. That's pretty crazy. Defaults should either be set *before* the page loads, or just allow the user to submit the default value with the form as is standard using `<option selected>`.

For example, this shows how to use a default value to change the contents of a form before it loads:

```
<?php
$vString = "one string"; //this is the default

if (isset($_POST["foo"]))
{
    $vString = $_POST["string"]; //overwrite the default if user submitted the form already
}
 echo $vString; //show the default on screen or the value the user submitted

//NOW go ahead and load the form...
...
echo "<select name='stringSelect'>
   <option ".($vString=='one string' ? 'selected' : '').">one string</option>
   <option ".($vString=='two string' ? 'selected' : '').">two string</option>
   <option ".($vString=='three string' ? 'selected' : '').">three string</option>
</select>";

//do something else with $vString here
?>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but having the options in an array would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Definately - I was just trying to keep it easy to understand for the OP